# core data insert object to existing object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Swift and iOS latest version

I created a core data object model with two entities: owner and car.

An owner can have multiple cars and a car inturn is connected to one owner only. Hence, i created one to many to car and inverse for car.

So if a owner is filtered, his details and cars can be displayed and if a car is taken, the car details and owner of the car can be used to proceed further.

FYI: the owner is unique i.e i made username unique so no duplicate owners

I created everything correctly and i am able to add owner but i have problem adding car later.

Code:

```
 let owner = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "owner", into: objectContext) as? owner

    owner?.name="Kaushik"
    owner?.address="address"
    owner?.mobile=12345789
    owner?.landline=123456789
    owner?.userName="KV"

    do
    {
        try objectContext.save()

    }catch
    {
        print("duplicate input")
    }


        var filteredOwner = [Any]()
      var  fetchREquest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "owner")
        fetchREquest.predicate=NSPredicate(format: "userName == %@","KV")
        do
        {
            filteredLender = try objectContext.fetch(fetchREquest)

        } catch
        {
            print("error")
        }

        let kvOwner = filteredLender[0] as? owner


        let bd =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "car", into: objectContext) as? car

    car?.make="Audi"
    car?.number=1234
    car?.modelname="A4"
   car?.owner=kvOwner

    kvOwner?.addToCars(car!)
    do
    {
       try objectContext.save()

    }catch
    {
        print("unable to add car\(error)")

    }
```

The problem is i am unable to add a car after a owner is added. i.e first owner is added.Then i fetch the owner again and then add the car

I am deliberately doing this way to check how it works if not given the first time.

But i am getting an error "unable to add car" every time i try to add a new car.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I recommend reading the section on Optional Binding in [Swift - The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) and adopting that approach in your code.  It will then be possible to see which (if any) of those variables is nil, which will assist in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: There is nothing nil over here..i am just adding the car

Answer (score 1):

The way i was doing this was..This code was added in Viewdidload(). Hence, everytime i started the app.I add the owner then i fetch the owner back and then add the car. The reason i did this was: to check if the owner is added the second time since owner is unique. So, after the first time, the owner throws error duplicate owner and after that i fetch the owner and tried to add the car which was throwing the error " Unable to add car".

As suggested by @Maor Duani, i added a if conditon before adding the car but that did not solve the problem. Instead i tried something else, i added a condition before owner to check whether owner already exists like

```
var filteredLender = [Any]()
    var  fetchREquest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Lender")
    fetchREquest.predicate=NSPredicate(format: "userName == %@","KV")
    do
    {
        filteredLender = try objectContext.fetch(fetchREquest)

    } catch
    {
        print("error")
    }
if(filteredLender.count==0)
{
}else
{
}
```

The above code is just rearranging the fetch before adding the owner. In this way, i check if owner is available and then add the owner and car. If not, i already have the fetched owner.So, i just add the car. In the end, this worked fine. It seems the problem might be with duplicate input. I am trying to add the same owner every time, i get duplicate error every time except first and then i am unable to add the car. When i removed that, it works fine. I don't understand why this happens. If anybody could explain this working, it would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Right after

```
let kvOwner = filteredLender[0] as? owner
```

Try this instead of your current code:

```
if let bd =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "car", into: objectContext) as? car {

   bd.make="Audi"
   bd.number=1234
   bd.modelname="A4"
   bd.owner=kvOwner

   do {
     try objectContext.save()

   } catch {
       print("unable to add car\(error)")

   }

}
```

Comment: Yep i tried..It goes inside the for loop but still throws an error "unable to add car "